# Rails disabled button on a canceled condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do a canceled logic around a button when the item is sent, the button will be disabled.

```
  if order.sent?

    else 

  order.cancel

  respond_to do |format|

    format.html { redirect_to request.referer.include? "cancel" ? request.referer : order_path(order.shopify_id), notice: 'Order cancelled successfully!' }

    end
  end
end
```

```
<div class="card-body">

      <%= link_to 'Cancel', order_path(@order.shopify_id), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
    </div>
```

I was wondering should I do it the if statement with the view or controller?

Comment: You can do this in view. There is no need to do this in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="card-body">
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', order_path(@order.shopify_id), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', disabled: @order.sent? %>
</div>
```

Change your view code to this. It will disable it when it's already sent.

Comment: ```<%= link_to('Cancel',
      order_path(@order.shopify_id), class: 'btn btn-danger',
      data: {
        disable_with: "Order Cancelled"
      }, method: :delete
    )
    %> ```

Comment: I'm glad you got your solution. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue :)